# Click treeview item without Id and Name

Tags: treeview, autoit, treeviewitem

How to click these items by name (`SingleLineText1`, `SingleLineText2`, etc.) in AutoIt? Example:

[image]

`TreeWidget > Screen1 > Programm1 > SingleLineText1 + SingleLineText2 + SingleLineText3`
have no Id and Name. The software is [HDPlayer for led screens](http://nexled.ru/download/HDPlayer.5.3.98.0.zip).

Comment: Please add a bare minimum example to demonstrate your exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the window being focused and not being able to use the mouse or keyboard temporarily while the script is running, you could use controlfocus() to focus the tree control and then use send() or ControlSend() to send up/down arrow keys and then F2 to followed by ctrl-c to copy the name to the clipboard, then send escape to exit text editing mode and use ClipGet() to check if the selected item is the name you want.

A dirty hack but I have used something like this successfully before.